# Creating forumla for sum of products in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

[image: Picture of Example]

I need help creating a formula for row 8 that will give me the sum of the products for cost * quantity of that month. The spreadsheet I am working with is 50+ columns and 1100+ rows.

The hand calculation for this is

B8 = (5 * 10) + (1 * 0) + (10 * 0) + (3 * 0) + (6 * 3 ) = 68

C8 = (5 * 0) + (1 * 0) + (10 * 3) + (3 * 8) + (6 * 0) = 54

D8 = (5 * 0) + (1 * 0) + (10 * 0) + (3 * 0) + (6 * 3) = 5

etc

Comment: Sum of products =  the `SUMPRODUCT` formula :-)

Comment: The constraints for SUMPRODUCT are (array1, array2, array3) what would I enter for that? Would I have to manually select (A2:B2, A3:B3, A4:B4) for the arrays?

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT($A$2:$A$6,B$2:B$6)`.

Answer (score -2):

In B8: =$a2*b$2+$a3*b$3+$a4*b$4+$a5*b$5+$a6*b$6

Once entered just drag to right to column F.

Due to order of operations parenthesis are not required but could be included for clarity.

HTH

Comment: Why not use `SUMPRODUCT`? This is the textbook case for it.

Comment: Ben, you are correct. I've always had a problem wrapping my head around SumProduct, thus my reluctance to use it.

Comment: Feel free to "steal" the "answer-I-posted-in-comments" as an edit to your answer :-)